# Best PostgreSQL HA strategy for 99% read scenario?

Tags: performance, postgresql, replication, high-availability

I'm in the process of building out a new PostgreSQL (9.3) environment in which traffic hovers around 99% read. We'll have 2 very powerful machines, connected via 1Gb ethernet. With the multitude of replication and failover options available in the 9.x release, what's the best option for a high-read scenario? A solution in which the standby server also acts as a read-only slave would be ideal.

Answer (score 0):

Use the built-in binary replication.  Unless you have a reason not to use it, that should be the default choice.

Reasons not to use it include the requirement to do partial replication and cross-version or cross-platform replication.  I don't think that applies to you.

Comment: Thanks Peter, that's where I've been headed. However, I'm also looking to account for automatic failover for high-availability.